# Installing an OAuth app in G-Suite

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace

I would like to try out the recently added G-Suite admin feature where one can whitelist third party OAuth apps using a test G-Suite account:

https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2017/07/manage-access-to-third-party-apps-with.html

In my test G-Suite account, I have one admin user and two regular users. The issue is that I am not able to install an OAuth app in such a way that it would show up under 'Security -> G Suite API Permission -> Installed' in G-Suite admin panel. I have tried these approaches so far:

1. Using a regular user account, I installed a few marketplace apps like Asana, 5pm etc. that show up at this url under the regular user account: https://myaccount.google.com/permissions.
2. Using a regular user account, I visited a bunch of websites and signed up using Google Authentication.
3. Using the admin account, I installed a bunch of market place apps using  'Apps -> Marketplace apps' page in admin panel.

My question is how can I install a random app such that it would show up under 'Security -> G Suite API Permission -> Installed'? In my production G-Suite account, I see a ton of apps such as 'Zoom', 'Expensify', 'Dropbox' , 'iOS', 'Reflektive', 'Dialpad' at this page but I am not able to repro this in my test G-Suite account.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to go to one of the apps you would like to test, for example dropbox.com and sign-in with and email address on your test Google domain. Make sure to allow the requested access. Afterwords you should be able to see the app under G Suite Permissions -> Installed.